# PHP DateTime class just like v5.3 for PHP 5.2

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.3, php-5.2

I've found a few problems in applications I've been doing where methods like DateTime::diff would be of much assistance, but my host with PHP 5.2 does not support DateTime::diff or any other from 5.3.

Can anyone point to a class implementation similar to PHP's DateTime class from v5.3, but working for PHP 5.2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having had to write much code to cover functionality of this sort for Moodle in the past, I can tell you from experience that it's a *very* tall order. I don't like being the bearer of bad news, but I think you 'll be hard pressed to find a good port for PHP 5.2 -- who would go to all the trouble *after* 5.3 became available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use following wrapper class in my php5.2 apps: http://pastebin.ca/2051944. Untill php5.3 was released - it saves much my time

Comment: looks nice, but I'm hoping not to convert all my dates to the new class

Comment: Broken link, anyway we can get this posted here instead?